# Android Studio удаляет строку import неправильно написанные библиотеки

Tags: android, импорт

Не мог подключить библиотеку `java.time.LocalDate;`
Нажал `Alt+Enter`, что-то кликнул, и теперь при вводе любой неправильной библиотеки эта строка удаляется, например, ввожу:
 `import java.util.kjkj;` и оно тут же ее удаляет.
 Создание другого проекта не исправляет эту фичу. 
Как отключить эту функцию Android Studio?

Comment: А зачем вам импорты несуществующих библиотек?

Comment: отключите в настройках "fly import" , точное название и местоположение я не помню, а посмотреть сейчас возможности нет.

Comment: Спасибо, нашел : File- Settings-Editor-General-Auto Import, снял галку Optimize imports on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File- Settings-Editor-General-Auto Import, снял галку Optimize imports on the fly

Answer (score 0):

Такая же проблема, убрал галочку на "Optimize imports on the fly" Импорт действительно не удаляется, но теперь он просто подсвечивается и подчеркивается серым цветом.